# Assign matrix cell values using variable in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, focal-statistics, matrix

I am trying to create a mask for focal analyses in GEE, and need a function that creates an n x n matrix (values = 0). Then I would like to assign values across a "diameter" of the matrix based on a certain angle. For example, for n = 5 and angle= 45

```
var kernel = 
  [[0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Here is what I have so far. The code correctly identfies the correct index `(row, col)`, but it will not assign the values to the matrix. The issue seems to be with the `row` variable. Perhaps GEE is not interpreting it as an integer? I added `.int()` to its calculation, but no luck. BTW, this code works for 45 degrees, but I am aware it still needs work to be robust to other angles (the printed `row`/`col` values are correct). Assigning values to the matrix cells with a calculated variable (`col`) is the part i'm stuck on.

```
var n = 9 // must be odd
var degrees = 45; // set angle
var midpoint = ee.Number(n).divide(2).ceil() // find midpoint of matrix 
var radians = degrees * (Math.PI/180);

// create n by n matrix
var a = [ ];
for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
    a[i] = [ ];
    for(var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        a[i][j] = 0; 
    }
}

// assign some values based on trigonmetry
for(var col = 0; col < n; col++){
  var x = ee.Number(col).subtract(midpoint).add(1)
  var y = x.divide(ee.Number(radians).tan()).round()
  var row = midpoint.add(y).subtract(1)
  print(ee.List([row,col]))
  a[col][row] = 1;
}
print(a,'a')
```

When I `print(a)` I get a matrix of all zeros. I think `row` is not defined to be useful as an array index. However, if I replace  `a[col][row] = 1;` with `a[col][2] = 1;` then it adds 1s in the specified column.

---

[@NoelGorelick's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/470927/115) was the issue. I hadn't realized the distinction between client side and server-side Math.* functions. I still need to adjust the math to get it to behave correctly, but can now edit the proper rows/cols as expected

```
var n = 9 // must be odd
var degrees = 45; // set angle
var midpoint = Math.ceil(n/2) // find midpoint of matrix 
var radians = degrees * (Math.PI/180);

// create n by n matrix
var a = [ ];
for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
    a[i] = [ ];
    for(var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        a[i][j] = 0; 
    }
}

// assign some values based on trigonmetry
for(var col = 0; col < n; col++){
  var x = col-midpoint+1
  var y = Math.round(x/Math.tan(radians))
  var row = midpoint+y-1
  print(ee.List([row,col]))
  a[row][col] = 1;
}
print(a,'a')
```

Comment: Please don't include solutions/answers within the area reserved for questions.  They should be written as (self-)answers in the area reserved for answers instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing client-side and server-side objects.
`row` is a computed value that only exists on the server.  You're trying to use it as an index with the `[]` operators.  You can't do that.  Either keep everything on the server (using only ee functions) or everything on the client using normal math (+, -, *, /, Math.tan, etc).